# Cannot assign to read only property 'whatever' of object #<Object>?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
let filteredArray = data
        .filter((object) =>
            isFilterInArray(filterBy, Object.values(object))
        )
        .forEach((object) => {
            Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
                object[key] = markHighlightedText(filterBy, object[key]);
            });
        });
```

It should be filtering initially the items that an array contains based on a **filterBy** value.

Once I filter it, I'm trying to modify each value and do some stuff, but then the

```
object[key] = markHighlightedText(filterBy, object[key]);
```

is failing with the following error:

[image]

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Looks like you need to map it to a new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re trying to change non-configurable property attributes

> A TypeError is thrown when attempts are made to change non-configurable property attributes (except value and writable, if permitted) unless the current and new values are the same.
>
> From [MDN - Modifying a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#modifying_a_property)

And because you got the key from `Object.keys` it’s mean the property is also enumerable

> The enumerable property attribute defines whether the property is picked by `Object.assign()` or spread operator. For non-Global_Objects/Symbol properties it also defines whether it shows up in a `for...in` loop and `Object.keys()` or not.
>
> From [MDN - Modifying a property - Enumerable attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#modifying_a_property)

Mapping it to a new object as [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)  commented, will fix that issue

```js
let filteredArray = data
  .filter((object) => isFilterInArray(filterBy, Object.values(object)))
  .map((object) => {
      // We are creating new object and not assigning to the original one because
      // some object keys aren’t writable (can’t assign to them)
      // but enumerable - meaning we get them in the Object.keys
      return Object.keys(object).reduce((newObject, key) => {
        newObject[key] = markHighlightedText(filterBy, object[key]);
        return newObject;
      }, {});
  });
```

Comment: I'm trying but I cannot find the code solution... any help?